# Fourier series for absolute value of sin functiom

Tags: fourier-analysis

If we take the absolute value for sin function, then it becomes even.

However, isn't period of this function $\pi$?

To find fourier series, 1.Even 2. period $2 \pi$.

Can we just treat this function as period $2\pi$?

Comment: If a function is periodic with period $T$, then it is periodic with period $kT$, for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is $\pi$ periodic (and its Fourier series converge) then $f(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n e^{4 i \pi n x}$ so writing it $f(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}$ you have $c_{2n + 1} = 0$